# Preserve the order of symbols in sympy equation

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like to preserve the structure of equation in the following order.

*Note that this is in sympy.

`Eq=A*X+B*U`

where X,U is assigned to other equations.

Sympy expand my symbols with variables assigned elsewhere.
So it ends up being something like: B*x+B*x**2+3*A*x
What I want to do is preserver the order of A X B U.

Update for clarification:
Hi!  Thx for your reply.

1. After trying different options, I've found that by using Matrixsymbols, it is possible to not operate the elements in the matrix. However I still can't make it to show the desired order.
2. The reason for this is so that I can save this in a jupyter notebook, where the order might help explaining or taking notes for specific procedure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify the following: 1) Are you really sure that `A*X+B*U` expands to `Bx+Bx**2+3*A*x` and not something like `U*B+X*A`? 2) Can you elaborate a bit on why you want to do this? The entire point of processing equations symbolically is that these aspects can freely be handled by the symbolic engine (SymPy in your case). If you want to preserve the equation as it is, why not save it as a string?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an expression with variables, the value of those variables will be used during creation, e.g.

```
>>> x = cos(3)
>>> eq = x + 2
>>> eq
cos(3) + 2
```

So if you want eq to look like `x  + 2` you have to make sure that `x` is defined as Symbol `x`

```
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> eq = x + 2
>>> eq
x + 2
```

If you have multiple symbols and you want to control the ordering, use unevaluated expressions:

```
>>> A,B,X,U = symbols('A B X U')
>>> ax = Mul(A, X, evaluate=False)
>>> bu = Mul(B, U, evaluate=False)
>>> eq = Add(ax, bu, evaluate=False)
>>> eq
A*X + B*U
```

You can substitute in the values that you desire as

```
>>> eq.subs({U:x+x**2, X:3*x})
3*A*x + B*(x**2 + x)
>>> expand(_)
3*A*x + B*x**2 + B*x
```

Does that help with what you are trying to do?